# Store multiple quotes for a customer to be later approved and created as orders

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, quote

I want to build a different checkout system where the customer doesn't create an order upon checkout but his quote is permanently stored for a later review.
 
 The review will be a background process which needs to locate the quote and create an order from it. 
 
I am familiar with how to create an order from a quote. I am also familiar with how the quote works. It's tied to the cart and old quotes are deleted on a regular basis.
 
 
My question is how should I approach this problem? Should I somehow modify the cart functionality, copy the existing cart (and all its tables) into my own model, or modify the order functionality (such as adding a flag if it's approved or not).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, U can Inactive the quote once its created, So that in future u can use that quote.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that might work for you: create an observer for `sales_order_place_after` where you set the order status to "on hold", then use the "unhold" button to approve the orders.

You have to try out how well this integrates with your payment methods.